# C# Making a Thread wait for a Timer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I'm writing a C# program that runs two IRC connections at once.
The connections are threaded, and each thread starts like so:

```
MainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartMainProcessor));
            MainThread.IsBackground = false;
            MainThread.Start();

private void StartMainProcessor() {
            MainProcessor.Bot.Connect();
            //while (true) { }
        }
```

Bot.Connect() looks like this (somewhat abridged version):

```
public void Connect() {
            try {
                Client.Connect(IRCHelper.SERVER, IRCHelper.PORT);
            }
            catch (CouldNotConnectException e) {
                Reconnect(true);
                return;
            }

            try {
                Client.Listen();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Reconnect(false);
                return;
            }
        }
```

This works fine until the bot disconnects (which will always happen eventually, it's the nature of IRC).
When it disconnects, Reconnect() is called, which starts a timer. When that timer expires the bot is meant to then call Connect() again. The reason for the timer is that an IRC server will refuse an immediate reconnection sometimes.

However, once the Connect() method has ended, the Thread ends, and the program (console application) exits. (Client.Listen() is blocking)

I had previously overcome this problem by adding while (true) { } in StartMainProcessor()... But this eats up 100% CPU, and I'd really prefer a different solution.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Is it essential that the reconnect is made from the same thread as the previosu connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a signaling construct. For example, you could use something like an [AutoResetEvent](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_AutoResetEvent) to block the thread calling Reconnect, i.e. call Reconnect, start the timer and then block the thread. Then set the auto reset event in the timer expired event handler to allow the thread to continue (unblock) and call Connect.

I'm not a fan of spinning the processor - wastes huge amounts of CPU resources when you add infinite loops or [sleeps in loops](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Blocking_Versus_Spinning).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just `Thread.Sleep` inside `Bot.Reconnect`? That would keep your thread alive and wake it up when ready to call `Bot.Connect` again.

Comment: +1 A sleep/connect/listen loop is the obvious solution.  Probably not used by the OP because of all the posts saying that sleep() is an anti-pattern and timers must be used instead :((

Comment: I guess that makes more sense. I did indeed have the idea that Thread.Sleep() is bad. Guess I should listen to the internet less, haha. :) Thanks, Daren.

Comment: @MartinJames, `Thread.Sleep` **IS** an anti-pattern... it's relatively harmless, but it's still an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like that

```
private bool canExitThread;
private void StartMainProcessor()
{
    while (canExitThread)
    {
        //do the magic here
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); //make sure you allow thread to do the job, otherwise you will get 100 cpu usage

        //do the connecting, disconnecting, listening
    }
}
```

Also can you check if Client is connected? if so then you should be checking that within the main loop and if it's disconnected - call the connect method.

Hope that gives you an idea how to do it.

Also have a look the the article below, which might explain things a little bit more.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Icky! Don't do that... he can block on input, a semaphore or a manual reset event which tells him when to exit.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting server..");

            foreach (var connection in new[] {new Connection(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), new Connection(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))})
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(connection.Connect);

            Console.WriteLine("Server running. Press Enter to quit.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Connection //might be good to implement IDisposable and disconnect on Dipose()
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan _reConnectionPause;

        public Connection(TimeSpan reConnectionPause)
        {
            _reConnectionPause = reConnectionPause;
        }

        //You probably need a Disconnect too
        public void Connect(object state)
        {
            try
            {
                //for testing assume connection success Client.Connect(IRCHelper.SERVER, IRCHelper.PORT);
                Debug.WriteLine("Open Connection");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //You might want a retry limit here
                Connect(state);
            }

            try
            {
                //Client.Listen();
                //Simulate sesison lifetime
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Session end");
                Thread.Sleep(_reConnectionPause);
                Connect(state);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a `Main` method, so why don't we start there:

```
private static readonly MAX_NUM_BOTS = 2;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Thread> ircBotThreads = new List<Thread>();
    for(int numBots = 0; numBots < MAX_NUM_BOTS; numButs++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(()=>{StartMainProcessor();});
        t.IsBackground = false;
        t.Start();
        ircBotThreads.Add(t);
    }

    // Block until all of your threads are done
    foreach(Thread t in ircBotThreads)
    {
        t.Join();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
}

private static void StartMainProcessor() 
{
    MainProcessor.Bot.Connect();
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
// 30 second time out (or whatever you want)
private static readonly TimeSpan TIMEOUT = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);

// specify the maximum number of connection attempts
private static readonly int MAX_RECONNECTS = 10;

public void Connect() 
{
    bool shouldListen = false;
    // This is your connect and re-connect loop
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_RECONNECTS; i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            Client.Connect(IRCHelper.SERVER, IRCHelper.PORT);
            shouldListen = true;
        }
        catch (CouldNotConnectException e) 
        {
            // It's OK to sleep here, because you know exactly
            // how long you need to wait before you try and
            // reconnect
            Thread.Sleep((long)TIMEOUT.TotalMilliseconds);
            shouldListen = false;
        }
    }

    while(shouldListen)
    {
        try 
        {
            Client.Listen();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // Handle the exception
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very rough draft, but the concept is that you keep trying to reconnect until you fail. Once you connect, then you listen (I presume you listen for something in IRC) and you process the data until you decide that you no longer need to be doing that work.